# Intermediate search regular expression in python

Tags: python, string, search

I'm looking for a python code that will allow me to use the RE library. and use it for Intermediate search.

For example, I want to check if the star is inside a phrase; then if was, run for loop (the star is not exactly the first or the last letter):

partA * partB

Answer (score 0):

Looking for a specific character in a string in Python is a simple as

```
string = "partA * partB"

if "*" in string:
    # do stuff
```

I'm not sure what you're trying to do with the string if you find an asterisk in it, but it seems like you don't need a regex.